# Need some help in joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables 
status and admit table as follows:

Admit

```
cono|resno|date      |admit_disch
---------------------------------
05  |108  |2018-11-28|R 
05  |108  |2018-11-17|D
05  |108  |2016-03-07|A
```

Status

```
cono|resno |date      |in_out
-----------------------------
05  |108   |2018-11-28|I
05  |108   |2018-11-17|O
05  |108   |2016-06-05|O
05  |108   |2016-06-05|I
05  |108   |2016-03-18|O
05  |108   |2016-03-18|I
05  |108   |2016-03-07|I
```

I would like to join these tables to give me output as below:

```
cono|date      |resno|admit_disch |in_out
-----------------------------------------
05  |2018-11-28|108  |R           |I
05  |2018-11-17|108  |D           |O
05  |2016-03-07|108  |A           |I
05  |2016-06-05|108  |A           |O
05  |2016-06-05|108  |A           |I
05  |2016-03-18|108  |A           |I   
05  |2016-03-18|108  |A           |I
```

Comment: You've told us what you want, but what is your question here? What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: For the non matched entry in the Admit table, you are required `A` as admit_disch  ?

Comment: @Arulkumar, Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the result as for the non matched entry in the `Admit` table, you are required `A` as admit_disch, then the following will work.

Seeing your output the matched entry in the top ordering then the order by date, so I added a column `ManualOrder` to fix this issue:

```
SELECT cono, [date], resno, admit_disch, in_out
FROM (
    SELECT S.cono, S.[date], S.resno,
           CASE WHEN A.admit_disch IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ManualOrder,
           COALESCE(A.admit_disch, 'A') AS admit_disch,
           S.in_out
     FROM [Status] S
     LEFT JOIN Admit A ON A.cono = S.cono 
               AND A.resno = S.resno
               AND A.date = S.date 
) Q
ORDER BY ManualOrder DESC, [date] DESC
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b57d7a56b60c598630129a179c7974d)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Inner Join query

```
Select admit.cono, admit.resno, admit.date, admit.admit_disch, Status.in_out from admit Inner join Status ON admit.cono=Status=cono
```